# More voltage than supplied

Tags: voltage-measurement

I stripped the ends of a 14v DC power supply to power a small 6-12v DC motor. I first measured the voltage coming from the supply and found an actual 17 volts coming out, but then when I connect the motor to the supply I find the voltage across the motor to be 21v. What happened here? How does the motor have a larger potential difference across it than was supplied?

Comment: Some power supplies require a minimum load to achieve regulation, and they output a somewhat higher voltage if they don't see the minimum load.  This it not too uncommon.  In your case, when the power supply terminals are open circuit, there is no minimum load.

Comment: Do you have a diode in parallel to your motor?
In case you don't have, the backemf will cause spikes on your supply and you might measure a higher voltage.

Comment: Well written question, to the point.

Answer (score 2):

If your power supply is an unregulated linear type then the unloaded voltage will be higher than its rating. Depending on what it was it was designed to power it may not have a filter capacitor either, in which case the peak voltage will be higher that the average that your meter shows.

[image]

When a motor is running it also acts a generator, producing a voltage which is slightly less than the driving voltage. When powered from unfiltered rectified AC it will 'fill in the gaps' between the peaks, and raise the average voltage.

I ran a small 6V motor on rectified AC and the voltage shown on the meter rose by 35% (from 4.4V to 5.9V). In the oscilloscope trace below you can see a high frequency waveform which is the voltage generated by the motor, and two 'bumps' which are the rectified AC from the power supply. Without the motor connected those bumps go down to zero volts.

[image]

Comment: Good answer (with nice pics). I think this effect will only occur if there in NO capacitor in the PSU.  The RMS converter circuit/IC in the DMM may also contribute to the accuracy of the readings when unusual waveforms are measured.  Cheap meters just use an averaging circuit, a Fluke I think typically uses a true RMS circuit in most of their meters.